# CSS/JS: Get browsers default font size by API and not

Tags: javascript, css, browser, font-size

I have an angular component that will be used in two diffrent applications.
In one application, there will be a html-font size of 100% (16px as default but changing with the browsers default font size - so basicly whatever the user will choose).

In the other application the html-font size will be set to 16px. I can not change this.
So using "rem" in my component will not be rsponsive with the users font-setting for both applications.

Is there a way to access the browsers default font size by any JS API or CSS Property?

This would be a solution but it could cause layout jumps. So I do not really like this solution.

```
const getDefaultFontSize = () => {
const html = document.querySelector('html');

const initialFontSize = window
    .getComputedStyle(html)
    .getPropertyValue('font-size');

html.style.fontSize = 'unset';

const fontSizeMatch = window
    .getComputedStyle(html)
    .getPropertyValue('font-size')
    .match(/\d+/);

html.style.fontSize = initialFontSize;

if (!fontSizeMatch || fontSizeMatch.length < 1) {
    return null;
}

const result = Number(fontSizeMatch[0]);
return !isNaN(result) ? result : null;
```

};

Comment: There is no specific JS API to get all the font info you need. A big miss indeed. However, I'm using the Open Source [font-finder](https://github.com/andy-portmen/font-finder/blob/master/webx/v3/data/inject/analyze.js) browser plugin which code might include what you are looking for. Check line >46

[Font-Finder Site](https://add0n.com/font-finder.html)